# How to put this event inside .live

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function and I want to put it inside .live().
My problem is that this function works ok, but the next time "without refreshing" it doesnt work, so I am thinking in reseting the value of "blur" after its been executed. I have readed that this can be done using .blur() inside .live(), but I really dont know how to do it. Need to learn more about sintaxt and callback.

```
$(window).blur( function() {
    // our window is on blur
    if(overiFrame != -1 ){
        // mouse over iframe and blur we count a click
        llamarAjax(1, adTopSrc, adMidSrc, adBotSrc);
    } else if(overiFrame2 != -1 ){
        // mouse over iframe and blur we count a click
        llamarAjax(2, adTopSrc, adMidSrc, adBotSrc);
    }else if( overiFrame3 != -1 ){
        // mouse over iframe and blur we count a click
        llamarAjax(3, adTopSrc, adMidSrc, adBotSrc);
    }
});
```

Thank you

Comment: `live` won't help, sounds like a logic problem with changing `overiframe` variables. Use console to log the variables to see what their values are

Comment: the `undefined` is likely throwing an error then is it not?

Comment: But I think thats not the problem, because once is relaunched, the values are set again.
But you are right, the problem is that $().ready is not called again.

Comment: This function is inside 
$(document).ready(function () {
and inside $().ready it resets the values and after that is called the .blur() function. But after the flur I am not calling again the document ready. How can I solve it?

Comment: `ready` has nothing to do with it. Can bind to window without it

Comment: I am never accessing that function again once its loaded, thats why I think my problem is with "ready"

Comment: I have reset all the 3 values to -1, but its still not working.
Any other idea?

Comment: "not working" ??  does nything log to console when you change browser tabs or click on menu bar?

Comment: Its not showing again the values of overiFrame.
the console.log is also inside  $(document).ready(function () {}
So while I change tab or click on browser menu, is not showing values again. It only show the value again if I click in a textarea and then I change tab or go to the browser menu.
I appreciate your time Charlietfl

Comment: How can I simulate the click on another element? I think it only works in the textarea, but has a dinamic id, so I cant know its name.

Comment: @Bernardao, to simulate click on other element. `$(elementSelector).trigger('click');`

Comment: Its not working,
$('textarea').trigger('click');

Comment: @Bernardao `trigger()` executes the code you have formerly written in the event handler, so if you have not handled the click event for the `textarea`, `trigger()` will not work because it is not meant to simulate a native click.

Comment: @Deadlock sorry, I cant understand what you mean. How can I handle the click event for the textarea? Im starting in jquery

Comment: The only solution I have found is launching a reload through php of the onblur page.
How can I give you 2 votes or anything for your help.
Im a noob here.
Thank you very much.